# Installing JDK to a pool's compute nodes in Azure Batch

Tags: linux, azure, azure-storage, azure-batch

I have to install java on the Ubuntu server nodes in my pool. I am trying to do it by tasks but every time I try to install java through the task using below code :

```
 TaskAddParameter taskToAdd = new TaskAddParameter();
    taskToAdd.withId(taskId).withCommandLine(String.format("sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk"));
    // Associate resource file with task
    taskToAdd.withResourceFiles(getListOfResourceFiles(sas));
```

I get an error saying

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I tried the above way at Pool Level also by giving this command in the StartTask of the Pool but then also it gave me the same error.

I need to install java on my pool nodes so that I can run my java program on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this on the pool's [StartTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.batch.protocol.models._start_task).

For the `commandLine` you need to invoke a shell as described in the best practices guide [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples/tree/master/Python/Batch#azure-batch-on-linux-best-practices). So instead of:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

do:

```
/bin/bash -c "sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk"
```

Additionally, you should use the PoolAdmin AutoUser user identity so you do not have to invoke `sudo`. Please see [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-user-accounts) for more information.